# Take image from list using PK and show as part of another object in a ListBox in MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

Think it's a pretty simple problem I'm having but it's not something I've had to do before.

I have an MVVM project that links to a DAL that has two types of object, an Image and a Card. The images and cards both have separate tables, and the card contains three relationships connecting to the image table, so that there are three images linked to each card.

Now I have a ListBox in my XAML that uses a list of cards as a data source, but I want to display one of the images as part of the data template. Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCards}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding }" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="300" Text="{Binding CardName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Edit #1**
this is my card model:

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public int Image1 { get; set; }
    public int Image2 { get; set; }
    public int Image3 { get; set; }
}
```

and the image model is this:

```
public class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string Imagepath { get; set; }
    public string ImageName{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `card` model looks like this...

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image1 { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image2 { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image3 { get; set; }
}
```

...then it's a piece of cake, you just need to do this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCards}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Source="{Binding Image1}" />
                <TextBlock
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       Width="300"
                       Text="{Binding CardName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But if your `Card` model looks like this...

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public int Image1Id { get; set; }
    public int Image2Id { get; set; }
    public int Image3Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you are probably going to need to create a `CardViewModel` that has `BitmapImage` properties instead of `Id` properties, and you will need to map from your `Card` to the view model.

If you need to load an image from a file or convert from a `Bitmap` (which is not the same thing as a `BitmapImage`), here are a couple converters:

```
public BitmapImage Import(string path, bool isRelativePath)
{
    var fullPath = GetFullPath(path, isRelativePath);
    var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    return bitmapImage;
}

public BitmapImage BitmapToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    return bitmapImage;
}

public string GetFullPath(string path, bool isRelativePath)
{
    return isRelativePath ? FolderPaths.Application + @"\" + path : path;
}
```

Comment: @Tom, where you able to solve your problem? If not, where are stuck?

Comment: In the end I gave up and made a composite type, made it into a list and then used it as the data source. Thanks for the help in your answer.